# Применение паттернов в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Я создаю фон, который почему-то перекрывает позже созданный мною паттерн. Не могу понять, как сделать наоборот.

```js
const canvasPatterns = document.getElementById('fon');
    let ctx = canvasPatterns.getContext('2d');

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/L_Old_London.svg/220px-L_Old_London.svg.png';
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
        ctx.fillRect(25, 25, ctx.canvas.width - 50, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
    };

    const patternLine = document.getElementById('block');
    let patternCtx = patternLine.getContext('2d');
    patternCtx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    patternCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
    patternLine.style.display = 'none';

    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternLine, 'repeat');
    ctx.lineWidth = 50;
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasPatterns.width, canvasPatterns.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternLine, 'repeat');
    ctx.lineWidth = 50;
    ctx.strokeRect(25, 25, 100, 25);
```

```html
<canvas id="fon" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="block" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
```

Comment: Как надо? Чтобы серый фон был поверх узоров?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко именно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img.onload = function ()`

Выполнится только после того, как загрузится картинка, таким образом Вы сначала рисуете серый фон а затем уже то, что в Файле, решить проблему можно если рисовть абсолютно все после загрузки файла:

```js
const canvasPatterns = document.getElementById('fon');
    let ctx = canvasPatterns.getContext('2d');

    const img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/L_Old_London.svg/220px-L_Old_London.svg.png';
    img.onload = function () {
    
        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
        ctx.fillRect(25, 25, ctx.canvas.width - 50, ctx.canvas.height - 50);
        
        const patternLine = document.getElementById('block');
        let patternCtx = patternLine.getContext('2d');
        patternCtx.fillStyle = 'grey';
        patternCtx.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
        patternLine.style.display = 'none';

        ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternLine, 'repeat');
        ctx.lineWidth = 50;
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasPatterns.width, canvasPatterns.height);

        ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternLine, 'repeat');
        ctx.lineWidth = 50;
        ctx.strokeRect(25, 25, 100, 25);
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="fon" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="block" width="25" height="25"></canvas>
```